# How to consolidate rows in excel in this scenario

Tags: excel, numbers, vlookup

I have two Columns. Column A has Part Numbers, Column B has Makes. After cleaning up my table I end up with duplicates in Column A. What I want to do is be able to consolidate all the makes to one unique part number in Column A. I tried posting a pictures but I can't yet because this is my first question.

I hope this makes sense. I just want to be able to create a formula or something that consolidates the part number. This will allow me to do a vlookup and bring all the makes into one cell which is my goal. Thank you!

```
PART NUMBER MAKE      PART NUMBER    MAKE
23  HOVERTECHNICS     23    HOVERTECHNICS
25  CUSHMAN           25    CUSHMAN
26  ARGO              26    ARGO
45  ALLSTATE          45    ALLSTATE,CUSHMAN
45  CUSHMAN           46    CUSHMAN
46  CUSHMAN           63    ROKETA
63  ROKETA            64    CAN-AM,HUSQVARNA,KAWASAKI
64  CAN-AM            66    E-Z GO,KAWASAKI,SUZUKI,YAMAHA
64  HUSQVARNA         85    HARLEY-DAVIDSON
64  KAWASAKI          255   ARGO,CLINTON,FRONTIER-TML (Quadra), HEALD, HEALTH KIT
66  E-Z GO      
66  KAWASAKI        
66  SUZUKI      
66  YAMAHA      
85  HARLEY-DAVIDSON     
255 ARGO        
255 CLINTON     
255 FRONTIER-TML (Quadra)       
255 HEALD       
255 HEATH KIT
```

The end result that I wish for looks like the example on the right.

I'm not sure if this is possible on a mac, if so I have windows as well Excel 2007.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your source is in ColumnsA & B, with a header row in Row1, then copy B2 into D2 and:

in C2:  `=IF(A2=A3,"",A2)` copied down to suit,
in D3:  `=IF(A3=A2,D2&", "&B3,B3)` copied down to suit.

Then copy ColumnsC&D and Paste Special Values into a new sheet. Filter there to select blanks in the PART NUMBER column and delete selected rows. Unfilter.